# "100% with Div" with margin left auto

Tags: css

[image]

I have a page middle aligned with `margin: 0 auto;` which is the page content. I need my navigation to have also `margin-left: auto;` but also needs to go until the end of the screen, even if the user re-size or zoom out the page, this nav must really go until the end.

Now I have something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/Dc7XK/

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) - Please show at least some attempt at whatever it is you are trying to do. Most will see this `CSS` tagged question, notice there is no code, and then move straight on.

Comment: Please specify your question. You just don't tell us anything. I only understand that you might need constant width.

Comment: I love that site... @MiguelAntunes give us a fiddle with where you are now, we might be able to find a solution...

Comment: This is a misleading question, please edit to provide details or it is  not worthy of being as a question in this site

Comment: Now I have a div with 100% width, with a background image aligned to right, and over it I have my nav with `margin:0 auto; background-color: black;` and this works for most of screen resolutions, but i really wanted to have a more clean way to do it. Since if you zoom out the image will stick to the right and will be a gap between the image and the nav.

Comment: @MiguelAntunes Must I spell it out? **Show us what you have!**

Comment: Sorry guys, of course I have tried several approaches to this, I thought the image would make it more clear, I've created a sample fiddle with my actual code.

Comment: So the div with 100% width is just for your background image? If so, you should put a containing div inside it with margin auto and then put the navigation inside the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a containing div like this:

```
<div id="outter">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="navigation">
      lorem ipsum dolor 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
#outter{
  width:100%;
  background-color:#00ff00;
}
#container{
   width:500px;
   margin:auto;
   margin-top:20px;
   background-color:#ff0000;
   padding:20px;
}


#navigation{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  height:16px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

Set your outer div to 100%. 
Then have a containing div the width you want the page with margins set to auto. Finally, have your navigation set to 100% width of the container! Boom.

http://jsfiddle.net/Dc7XK/2/

I hope this is what you are after!

Comment: It's like that but with the red till right of screen, having just the green on left.

Comment: Try changing 'margin:auto;' to 'float:right;' in the container's css then.

Comment: Ok, I manage to get want I wanted, you can check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Cy7rJ/ Thank you.